# JQuery Focus - with input?

Tags: jquery, input, focus

AS I understand it, the focus event must be used with something like an input box, but that doesn't seem to be working for me. I have the following fiddle... I'm trying to get 'Guide' div to show up when someone focuses on the textbox. I'm not sure if part of the problem is my use of "siblings" and if the input box needs a unique ID? But I put the unique identifier as the parent and then referred to the sibling...

http://jsfiddle.net/jhacks/2jjZF/2/

You'll see I do have some extra code in there for 'Error' and 'Okay' messages. I'm working on getting the JQuery events for those to match something like the Twitter signup page If anyone can direhttps://twiter.com/signup but that's for another post.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input#registerBox').focus(
    function() {
     $(this)
       .closest('#registerBoxName') // go to parent div#registerBoxName
       .next('.registerGuidance')   // move to next div.registerGuidance
       .find('#registerGuideName')  // finding target #registerGuideName within div.registerGuidance
       .show(); // make display
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I used this code and it makes perfect sense as well. This post along side the other user's post regarding traversing were both incredibly useful. It finally works!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, siblings is the wrong selector. Siblings refers to other elements with the same parent, of which your input field has none.

Because you are using an ID selector, and ID's are unique be definition, there is no need to traverse.

```
$('input#registerBox').focus(
    function() {
        $('#registerGuideName').show();
    }
);
```

​
You are already using a jquery object with `$(this)` so why not just select that ID directly?

If your script requires traversing because you have multiples in your document, you need to use classes or data-attributes instead of an ID selector. Proper traversing would mean finding a mutual parent and then finding the appropriate child.

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

```
$('input.registerBox').focus(
    function() {
        $(this).closest('.registerName').find('.registerGuideName').show();
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for this help! For one, I fixed things and used classes where more appropriate. And now I know more about traversing, which is incredibly useful. Thank you!